# Java Selenium why compilator ignores lines?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

Compilator ignores my lines, which must print error number to console

```
  public static void linkTest(String[] urlList, String home)
        {
            int response;int error = 0;
    
            for(int i=0;i<=urlList.length;i++)
            {
                response = linkOpens(home+urlList[i]);
                if(response==200){}
                else
                {System.out.println("Http code "+response+" on ("+i+") "+home+urlList[i]);
                error++;}
            }    

            if(error==0){System.out.println("No Errors.");}//ignored
            else{System.out.println(error+" Errors!");}//ignored
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean 'compiler' instead of 'compilator'?

I'm guessing you expect to see output regarding http errors? Why do you expect http errors? Are you purposefully feeding your program a list containing urls which don't reply 200? Because if response is 200 your program doesn't print anything.

Basically, what is your input (what is the contents of urlList and of home) and what is your expected output vs actual output?

Comment: I need only see the problems , I have a big list of pages , and I have to check them opening for people with different roles on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlList[urlList.length]` is out-of-range and accessing it should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try changing the `for` statement to `for(int i=0;i<urlList.length;i++)` (Change `<=` to `<`).

Comment: oh! i forget about Exeption because of using try-catch... Thanks! it works now =) and knowledge of how to avoid this exception is very useful to me!